# Hundred errors while including windows.h

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2012

I'm running windows 7 64-bit and VS2012. When including windows.h I'm getting around 130 errors or so. and of course can't compile the project.

Did a short google research and I saw some people recommending installing the SDK again. I reinstalled but to no avail.

Then I tried to replace the windows.h file with the same file from my friend's pc where it works, but still I get the errors.

Then I tried to replace the whole include folder :D, still get the same 130 errors.

I also made sure that the "allow language extension" option is enabled in the project settings.

Any ideas?

---

So, I've done some more researching. If I start a new project and compile:

```
#include <windows.h>

void main()
{

}
```

It compiles well. Then I included my 2 .h files and then the errors appear (I'll mention again: while not including windows.h my project compiles flawlessly).

My two .h files contain 2 classes.

NumSet.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>

#define SIZE 5

using namespace std;

class NumSet
{
    private:
        int _arr[SIZE];
        int _numOfNumbers;

    public:
        NumSet(void);
        ~NumSet(void);

        int max();                      //returns a player's max number.

        bool insert(int newNum);
        int freeCells();
        bool replace(int index, int newNum);

        int min();

        float average();

        int biggerThan(int num);

        int smallerThan(int num);

        NumSet& operator+=(int num);

        NumSet& operator++();

        NumSet& operator--();

        bool operator==(const NumSet& src)const;

        NumSet operator=(const int * src);

        NumSet& operator=(const NumSet& src);

        bool del(int num);

        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, NumSet& numset);

        friend istream& operator>>(istream& out, NumSet& numset);
};
```

NumSet.cpp:

```
#include "NumSet.h"

NumSet::NumSet(void)
{

    for (int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)            //generating 5 random numbers between 1-10 and storing them in the array.
    {

        _arr[i] = (rand()%10) +1;
    }

    std::sort(&_arr[0],&_arr[5]);     //sorting the numbers.

    _numOfNumbers = 5;
}

NumSet::~NumSet(void)
{
}

int NumSet::max()
{
    int max = 0;

    for (int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        if (_arr[i]>max)
        {
            max = _arr[i];
        }
    }

    return max;
}

bool NumSet::insert(int newNum)
{
    if (freeCells()==0)
        return false;

    _arr[_numOfNumbers-1] = newNum;

    std::sort(&_arr[0],&_arr[5]);
}

int NumSet::freeCells()
{
    if (_numOfNumbers==SIZE)
        return 0;

    return (SIZE-_numOfNumbers);
}

bool NumSet::replace(int index, int newNum)
{
    if ((index<0 || index>SIZE) || (newNum<1 || newNum > 10))
        return false;

    _arr[index] = newNum;

    std::sort(&_arr[0],&_arr[5]);
}

int NumSet::min()
{
    int min = 11;

    for (int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        if (_arr[i]<min)
        {
            min = _arr[i];
        }
    }

    return min;
}

float NumSet::average()
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        sum += _arr[i];
    }

    return ((float)sum/SIZE);
}

int NumSet::biggerThan(int num)
{
    int count = 0;

    for (int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        if (_arr[i]>=num)
            count++;
    }

    return count;
}

int NumSet::smallerThan(int num)
{
    int count = 0;

    for (int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        if (_arr[i]<num)
            count++;
    }

    return count;
}

NumSet& NumSet::operator+=(int num)
{
    this->insert(num);

    return *this;
}



NumSet& NumSet::operator++()
{
    for (int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        _arr[i]++;

        if (_arr[i]==11)
        {
            _arr[i]= 1;
        }
    }

    return *this;
}

NumSet& NumSet::operator--()
{
    for (int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        _arr[i]--;

        if (_arr[i]==0)
        {
            _arr[i]= 10;
        }
    }

    return *this;
}

bool NumSet::operator==(const NumSet& src)const
{
    if (_numOfNumbers != src._numOfNumbers)
        return false;

    for (int i =0;i<_numOfNumbers;i++)
    {
        if (_arr[i] == src._arr[i])
            continue;

        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

NumSet NumSet::operator=(const int *src)
{
    if (sizeof(src)>(sizeof(int)*SIZE))
        return *this;

    NumSet newSet;

    for (int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        newSet._arr[i]= src[i];
    }

    return newSet;
}

NumSet& NumSet::operator=(const NumSet& src)
{
    for (int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        _arr[i]=src._arr[i];
    }

    _numOfNumbers=5;

    return *this;
}

bool NumSet::del(int num)
{
    if (num>SIZE)
        return false;

    _arr[num]=11;                           //setting the number to be deleted to 11 (there's no another way that 11 can be present in the array).

    std::sort(&_arr[0],&_arr[5]);           //sorting the array so the number to be deleted is in the end.

    _numOfNumbers--;                        //reducing the number of numbers in the array by 1, so the number to be deleted (the last in the array) will be ignored.
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, NumSet& numset)
{
    if (numset._numOfNumbers==0)
        cout << "\n\nEmpty NumSet." << endl;

    else
    {
        for (int i=0;i<numset._numOfNumbers;i++)
        {
            cout << numset._arr[i] << " ";
        }
    }

    return out;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& in, NumSet& numset)
{

    for (int i=0;i<numset._numOfNumbers;i++)
    {
        cout << "\n\nEnter your #" << i+1 << " number:" << endl;
        int newnum;
        cin >> newnum;
        numset.replace(i, newnum);
    }

    return in;
}
```

game.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "NumSet.h"


using namespace std;

class Game
{
    private:
        NumSet *player1, *player2;

        void humanVShuman();

        void humanVSpc();

        void pcVSpc();

    public:
        Game(void);
        ~Game(void);

        void game(int gameType);


};
```

game.cpp:

```
#include "Game.h"


Game::Game(void)
{
    player1 = new NumSet;
    srand(time(0));
    player2 = new NumSet;
}


Game::~Game(void)
{
}

void Game::game(int gameType)
{
    if (gameType==1)
        humanVShuman();

    else if (gameType==2)
        humanVSpc();

    else if (gameType==3)
        pcVSpc();
}   

void Game::humanVShuman()
{
    system("cls");
    cout << *player1 << endl;
    //Sleep(200);
    cout << *player2 << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}

void Game::humanVSpc()
{

}

void Game::pcVSpc()
{

}
```

And now for the interesting part:

In main.cpp. As long as I'm doing

```
#include "NumSet.h"
#include "Game.h"
#include <windows.h>
```

I'm getting a lot of errors in different h files such as wingdi.h and winuser.h.

If I'm not including my two h files NumSet and Game, and just including windows.h, it compiles with no errors.

If I'm including only my 2 h files, it compiles with errors.

So something in my 2 h files interrupts with windows.h. But what?

Comment: First, you really shouldn't have reinstalled the SDK and definitely shouldn't have replaced windows.h from your friend's machine.  If you can undo the windows.h replacement, do so.  Then add your code to this question.  We can't divine what's wrong by osmosis.

Comment: @CareyGregory +1 for adding a new word to my vocabulary.

Comment: Well, since you said 130 errors rather than 132 or 127 it is clearly the fact that you need more fiber in your diet that is causing your troubles.

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply.

Of course I backed up my files first, and already moved the originals back to their place.

Honestly I don't think the code it self matters as it is enough that I comment-out the #include <windows.h> line and the code compiles flawlessly, but of course I'd be happy to post it. As it is a project spread over 5 files, which one would you like to see? The .h file where I'm including the windows.h file?

Comment: Oh, geez, I just now noticed that you not only replaced windows.h but the entire include folder.  Dude, VS is not broken.  Your code is broken.  Quit f-ing with VS.  Uninstall the whole mess (and that won't be easy), reinstall it with default choices, leave it the heck alone, and figure out what's wrong with your code.

Comment: If you can restore it to the state it was in when you installed it then yes, do so.  Then recompile.  Post the file that includes windows.h and the first 10 error messages you get.

Comment: You may be having issues between 32/64 bitness. Can you post the errors to give more info and paths that you are referencing?

Comment: "Any ideas?" Yes. Quit replacing files without having any idea of what you're doing. :-)

Comment: Need more info.  Either small code that shows the problem or list of error.

Comment: Can you show us what [some of] the errors are? **Edit:** Oh, if you're doing like others have suggested and *modifying* the Windows headers, then that's not going to work. Stop doing it. Reinstall the Windows SDK if you need to, in order to get pristine copies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SIZE` is already defined in `windef.h`.  You don't want to redefine it.  Change it to `MY_SIZE` or something else in your `NumSet.h`.  Then It compiles on my machine (vs2012 on Win7).

And also, you have some function names like `max` and `min` in your `NumSet`.  Better avoid those.  We already have that kind of macros defined in standard headers.  Try some other names.  Or it will give you some pains.

Comment: Wouldn't including the OP's header file _after_ `windows.h` also solve this problem? Granted that `SIZE` is redefined, but this happens after the `windows.h` stuff that gets included.

Comment: @BhargavBhat No. According to my VS2012, include the header after `windows.h` will give you tons of errors :)

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the input though. Isn't as straightforward as I thought it would be.

Comment: @BhargavBhat That's because the OP define something like `max` and `min` in his class, which are already defined in standard headers :P Bad naming.

Comment: The `min` and `max` functions are defined within the scope of the class `NumSet`, so they shouldn't interfere with the `windows.h` stuff at all.

Comment: @BhargavBhat No. `min` and `max` are macros, instead of functions.  VS2012 will complain about these.

Comment: The fact that `min` and `max` are defined as macros in `windows.h` is terrible and causes lots of problems when trying to use 3rd-party code. For instance, see http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/22133. Fortunately, you can use `NOMINMAX` to prevent `windows.h` from defining them.

Answer (score 4):

First, I'd recommend making `windows.h` the first thing you include. That way, any errors you get will be seen as errors in *your* code rather than errors in `windows.h`, and that way you can fix them.

Second, try using `#define NOMINNMAX` before you include `windows.h`. This will prevent `windows.h` from generating the macros `min` and `max` (the names of which are frankly incredibly terrible, and MS should feel bad for choosing those names). That way, you can still use your functions `min` and `max` (or, as gongzhitaao suggested, you can rename them anyway).

(Gongzhitaao's suggestion of using something other than `SIZE` is probably also correct.)

EDIT: More information on `NOMINMAX`: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/143208

Comment: Note that some MS code does use the `min` and `max` macros, so this solution won't always work. I *think* that this is only true of MFC code, though I could be wrong.

Comment: The gdiplus*.h headers use them.  Best to just #undef them after the #include.